# R data frame - aggregating multiple columns at once

Tags: r

With a data frame df like below

```
----------------------
a     |  b    |  c 
------+-------+-------
true  | true  | true
false | true  | false
false | false | false
true  | true  | false
```

I need to find the % of `"true"` for each of the columns a, b and c as a data frame such that it can be used in a ggplot. How to go about it ?

Note:- `"true"` is not the logical `TRUE`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We reshape the 'wide' to 'long' format using `gather`, then find the `mean` of 'true' per each 'group', and use `geom_bar` to do a bar plot

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
gather(df1, group, value) %>% 
       group_by(group) %>% 
       summarise(perc= mean(value=="true")) %>% 
       ggplot(., aes(x=group, y=perc)) + 
               geom_bar(stat="identity") +
               scale_y_continuous(labels = percent)
```

NOTE: Assume that the columns are `character` class

Comment: This works well, observe that the `groups` are sorted alphabetically - is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: @user3206440  You can use `group_by(group=factor(group, levels = lvls)) %>%`